# How can I have an autocompletable input field in emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to make a function that will ask the user for the path to a file, and then do some stuff depending if the file exists or not. I know about the `(interactive "s")`, and I tried using it, but, pressing TAB doesn't suggest possible path names. 
How can I prompt for a path, and store it in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `read-file-name`. Try pressing <kbd>C-h f</kbd> and enter `read-file-name` to read the documentation.

Here's some example code that reads a file name:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (setq file (read-file-name "File: "))
  (message "You chose: %s" file))
```

Comment: No, you want @scottfrazer's answer.  Don't reimplement Emacs inside Emacs just because you can't M-x describe-function interactive :)

Answer (score 6):

With interactive, you should use `f` for an existing filename, or in your case, `F` for a possibly non-existent one:

```
(defun foo (filename)
  (interactive "F")
  (if (file-exists-p filename)
    ...
```

Comment: Also worth noting; if you want a prompt, just tack it right on to the interactive format string: `(interactive "FFile: ")`

Answer (score 3):

The following code shows how you could do this (replace the error sexps with code to handle scenario where file exists or not):

```
(defun do-stuff-with-file (filename)
  "Do stuff with a file."
  (interactive (list (read-file-name "Do stuff with file: ")))
  (when (file-exists-p filename)
    (error "%s already exists" filename))
  (when (not (file-exists-p filename))
    (error "%s doesn't exist" filename)))
```